# Send and receive JSON through same function in Volley

Tags: java, android, json, gson, android-volley

I am using Android Volley library for making API calls. I want to send JSON object and in turn receive JSON object in response, but not able to do that.

Here is my code

```java
private void registerUser() {
    try
    {
        User user=new User(name,name,email,phone,password);
        Gson userGson=new GsonBuilder().create();
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        params.put("user",user);
        JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL
                ,params,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {

                try
                {
                    String res=response.getString("status");
                    Log.e("String Res",res);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    ...
           }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                   ...
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("exception at last",e+"");
    }

}
```

I am trying this on my local server making a simple JSON file. Kindly help.

Comment: Please mention issue you are facing.  Don't ask us for any issue.

Comment: mainly I get volley errors like server timeout error or so. So I am afraid that is it because of local server

Comment: server timeout issue :- Means your local server is not responding.

Comment: I get response from the local server itself when either I just send JSON or recieve JSON , but here since I am doing both, facing this issue

Comment: Add output of your response.

Comment: I am not getting any output for this activity. Output I receive is for different activities not this one

Comment: You are testing with simulator or real devices?

Comment: real device @Krish not on emulator.

Comment: Did you check your server log files ?

Comment: yup. But the basic thing is I am able to call different APIs through this same server. Just this one is not responding

Comment: Then you have to check the server code instead of android code.